# Windows mail server that supports username wildcard aliases?

Tags: windows, smtp, alias, pop3

Is there any free mail server (in this case POP3) for Windows that supports aliases?

e.g.

```
User name: iboyd
Aliases:   ian@serverfault.com
           ian.*@serverfault.com
           amanda@serverfault.com
           *@ianboyd.com

User name: bob
Aliases    bob@serverfault.com
           bob.*@serverfault.com
           *@chryston.co.uk

User name: marie
           marie@serverfault.com
           marie.*@serverfault.com
           *@tecumseh.com
```

For years i have been using my own custom-written POP3 server that worked with the Window's built-in SMTP service (since there was no POP3 server). i want to move off Windows 2000 Server to Windows Server <strike>2003</strike> <strike>2008</strike> <strike>2008 R2</strike> 2012, and i'm dreading having to re-configure the built-in SMTP server with the external [COM object extensions that added greylisting](http://www.proxmea.com/). Plus it would be useful to have a product that handled RBL/SBL and graylisting in one product.

But a feature i require is wildcard aliasing of e-mail addresses, with user accounts that are independent of host names.

i've tried [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/). And while it looks like i might support aliases:

[image]

It doesn't actually work, as only one test e-mail ends up in my account, rather than a half-dozen:

```
+OK POP3
user ian@serverfault.com
+OK Send your password
pass serverfault
+OK Mailbox locked and ready
list
+OK 1 messages (185 octets)
1 185
.
```

The reason i want a **Windows** SMTP & POP3 server is that i have no interest anymore in editing config files.

---

**Note:** Even hMailServer isn't really want i want, because user accounts exist under a domain, rather than independant of it, i.e.

> ian@serverfault.com

and

> joesmith@ianboyd.com

would would to be separate user accounts, because they are separate domains.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Mercury 32. The user accounts are stand-alone and not tied to Windows in anyway. The wildcard aspects may be difficult in the per user basis as you have presented, but can possibly be addressed through its rules processing.